# Java- understanding the logic of reverse in array

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

I have a dynamic string class which has a char array `text` and it has a `reverse()` method that can reverse the contents of the array.

But i dont understand the logic of how the algorithm works. Could you be so kind as to walk me through the code?

```
public void reverse() {
  char tmp;
    for(int i=0; i<length/2; i++) {
      tmp = text[i];
      text[i] = text[length-1-i];
      text[length-1-i] = tmp;
    }
 }
```

Comment: take a piece of paper and trace the values of the array and `i` or use a debugger and step through the code line by line.

Comment: If you don't understand the algo then the best way to understand it is to use a pen and paper and trace the steps. Do it for different examples and you'll understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a string and try to reverse it. The string is "coder"

`length` = length of string = 5 (in this case)

`length/2` = 5/2 = 2 (it won't be 2.5 since we are dividing two integers)
So the for loop goes from 0 till 2 (0,1, NOT 2)

When `i` = 0 :

`temp` = 'c' 
`text[0]` will now hold `text[5 - 1 - 0]`

so now text is 'roder' (Intermediate answer)

`text[4]` will now hold 'c' 
So now text is 'rodec'

When `i` = 1 :

`temp` = 'o' 
`text[1]` will now hold `text[5 - 1 - 1]`

so now text is 'redec' (Intermediate answer)

`text[3]` will now hold 'o'

So now text is 'redoc'

The reason the for loop is till `length/2` is because, we are swapping the characters from the two ends, and stop in the middle.

I hope this helps. Try taking a longer string now and follow the same steps.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I understand how it works now thanks to you. Btw i didnt just post my question here without trying to put an effort on how it works. I did try to go through the algorithim but i just couldnt comprehend it.

Answer (score 0):

You should think and debug all steps in the loop like this

```
Char[] text ='abcd'
text.length = 4
```

first step,

```
temp = 'a' 
text[0] = text[3] // text[0] = 'd'
text[3] = temp // text[3] = 'a'
// your text = 'dbca'
```

second step,

```
temp = 'b'
text[1] = 'c'
text[2] = 'b'
// your text = 'dcba'
```

You can find reversed text in two times -> size/2

Comment: Whats confusing me most in the code is the line  text[i] = text[length-1-i];. Am i right to think that the reason for why the forloop length is divided by half is because its swapping 2 numbers at a time. The last to the first etc.

Comment: You get arrayindexoutofboundsexception if you use text[length-i]. Because array starts from zero but your text length equals array.size+1